# Dynamically loading templates (partials) using Blaze Meteor.js

Tags: templates, meteor, dynamic, meteor-blaze

Is there any way to dynamically load a template with onCreated method of Meteor.js? I have different template and one display area (main template).

```
<template name="main">

</template>
```

default loaded template

```
<template name="default">
</template>
```

Loaded templates via links

```
<template name="page1">
</template>

<template name="page2">
</template>
```

Is there a way I can use oncreated function to load the default, and remove (default) and load other template in the same main template when they are clicked?

Comment: Why necessary in oncreated?

Comment: Just believe onCreated renders default components. In anyway, the crux is to be able to render pages dynamically. I don't want it to be static like ```{{> main }}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Template.dynamic](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic).

It allows you to load a template only by its name. Easy thing here because you can let your template handle dynamic names by using a Reactive var or Reactive Dict.

Declare some templates:

```js
<template name="main">
 {{> Template.dynamic template=getTemplateName }}

 <button class="loadTemplate" data-target="page1">Load Page 1</button> 
 <button class="loadTemplate" data-target="page2">Load Page 2</button> 
</template>

<template name="page1">
</template>
<template name="page2">
</template>

<template name="default">
</template>
```

In your main template you can set in `onCreated` the default template name `default`:

```js
Template.main.onCreated(function(){
  this.state = new ReactiveDict();
  this.state.set("targetTemplate", "default");
})
```

Get the template to load via helper:

```js
Template.main.helpers({
  getTemplateName() {
    return Template.instance().state.get("targetTemplate");
  },
})
```

And set the new template name by button click event:

```js
Template.main.events({
  'click .loadTemplate'(event, templateInstance) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const targetName = $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-target');
    templateInstance.state.set("targetTemplate", targetName);
  }
})
```

You can of course do this also by other events than only by clicking a button, since it depends on a ReactiveDict / ReactiveVar it will render the new template if the variable updates.

Note: Very important is to handle the data that is passed to the template, too. Once your dynamic template becomes more complex you have to be more aware of that, too.

Comment: I'm short of words of appreciation. Thanks a bunch. God bless.